# Bootstrap weighed median and confidence interval

Tags: r

I'm using the below code to bootstrap a confidence interval for a median, which works just fine.

```
library(boot)
data <- c(6, 11, 7, 8, 3, 9, 4, 1, 1, 8, 2, 2, 5, 3, 1)
weight <- c(0.839432605459112, 0.774215027235327, 0.709256693551626, 0.809376516981207, 0.809698716683444, 0.880849581474519, 0.829263837448813, 1.80390621483409, 1.12749447791778, 0.93389158146594, 1.07832286911631, 0.79541512406283, 1.06708509325217, 0.946752658104578, 0.968003233015867)
Mboot = boot(data, function(x,i) median(x[i]), R=10000)
boot.ci(Mboot, conf = 0.95,  type = c("norm", "basic" ,"perc"))
```

However, I would like to calculate the bootstrapped *weighed* median for this and only found how I can either calculate the weighed median *or* bootstrap it.

Comment: Can you put `dput(data)` in your question? Also, please indicate the important packages that you are using.

Comment: See updated question

Comment: It will be difficult to reproduce your problem without a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Comment: The main problem, as pointed out in the question, is not the error message but the question how to bootstrap a weighed median with confidence interval, so the latter part can be ignored.

Comment: Well, we can't help you in bootstrapping a weighted median if we don't know the weights, in the first place. Your data is just a vector, and we don't know the weights of each element of the vector.

Comment: see edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to multiply `data` by `weight` and do bootstrap on the product.

```
library(boot)
Mboot_w = boot(data * weight, function(x,i) median(x[i]), R=10000)
Mboot_w
boot.ci(Mboot_w, conf = 0.95,  type = c("norm", "basic" ,"perc"))
```

---

Let's break down the bootstrapping procedure. Essentially, the `R=10000` produced 10000 samples with replacement of the product. 
Then the median of each bootstrap is computed.  You now have a sampling distribution of weighted medians.

```
df <- data * weight
weighted_medians <- replicate(10000, median(sample(df, length(df), replace = T)))
```

The bootstrap weighted median is:

```
median(weighted_medians)
```

Using quantiles, a 95% confidence interval is

```
quantile(boot_medians, c(.025, .975))
```